# Debian Installer – screen blanks

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I want to install Debian on my new Lenovo Yoga 730.

I got an installation image onto a USB, but when I tried selecting Debian Installer or Graphical Debian Installer, the screen goes black and nothing ever comes up.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/q/1061488/354511) question of the same issue on Super User and tried following the proposed solution, but it did not work on my system; I have the same black screen.

Instead now I have gotten a Live CD image on a USB, and the Linux Live works fine; I can boot that up no problem.

However the installer option still fails.

When I look at the Graphical Debian Installer option commands now, they are different:

```
setparams 'Graphical Debian Installer'
    Linux /d-i/gtk/vmlinuz append video=vesa:ywrap,mtrr vga=788 "${loopback}"
    Initrd /d-i/gtk/initrd gz
```

I dont know what the difference is, but since the Live CD at least works, I feel like there should be a way to get the installer to work.

Can anyone help me fix the screen disappearing?

Comment: Following the instructions in the link you posted, did you learn if the boot process hangs anywhere? On a different note, maybe this applies? https://askubuntu.com/questions/946480/installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-on-lenovo-yoga-720 (slightly different version number).

Comment: (1) Please review my edit and verify that I didn’t make any mistakes.  (2) It might (or might not) help if you follow the lead of the question you linked to and describe your system. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I couldnt see if the boot process hangs anywhere. The person in that response was able to get text output with the first thing he did, but that didnt work for me, I still have no text output.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install Debian on my new Lenovo Yoga 730.
>
> Can anyone help me fix the screen disappearing?
>
> When I look at the Graphical Debian Installer option commands now, they are different:

```
setparams 'Graphical Debian Installer'
  Linux /d-i/gtk/vmlinuz append video=vesa:ywrap,mtrr vga=788 "${loopback}"
  Initrd /d-i/gtk/initrd gz
```

See the answer you linked to: "[Black screen when trying to install Ubuntu or Debian on new laptop](https://superuser.com/q/1061488/354511)":

> "In the grub screen, I typed "e" to edit the "Graphical Install" entry. Then I ..."

Following those instructions ought to give a hint where it's getting hung up.

You can also try the text installer, if *just getting it installed* is your only concern.

Also see: "[5.3. Boot Parameters - Chapter 5. Booting the Installation System](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s03.en.html)":

One thing that jumps out on that webpage is:

> "**debian-installer/framebuffer (fb)**
>
> Some architectures use the kernel framebuffer to offer installation in a number of languages. If framebuffer causes a problem on your system you can disable the feature using the parameter vga=normal fb=false. Problem symptoms are error messages about bterm or bogl, a **blank screen**, or a freeze within a few minutes after starting the install.".

See also section "**5.3.2. Debian Installer Parameters**

> - **debconf/priority (priority)**
>
>   This parameter sets the lowest priority of messages to be displayed.
>
>   The default installation uses **priority=high**. This means that both high and critical priority messages are shown, but medium and low priority messages are skipped. If problems are encountered, the installer adjusts the priority as needed.
>
>   If you add **priority=medium** as boot parameter, you will be shown the installation menu and gain more control over the installation. When **priority=low** is used, all messages are shown (this is equivalent to the expert boot method). With **priority=critical**, the installation system will display only critical messages and try to do the right thing without fuss.
> - **DEBIAN_FRONTEND**
>
>   This boot parameter controls the type of user interface used for the installer. The current possible parameter settings are:
>
>   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
>
>   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text
>
>   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=newt
>
>   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=gtk
>
>   The default frontend is **DEBIAN_FRONTEND=newt**. **DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text** may be preferable for serial console installs. Some specialized types of install media may only offer a limited selection of frontends, but the **newt** and **text** frontends are available on most default install media. On architectures that support it, the graphical installer uses the **gtk** frontend.
> - **BOOT_DEBUG**
>
>   Setting this boot parameter to 2 will cause the installer's boot process to be verbosely logged. Setting it to 3 makes debug shells available at strategic points in the boot process. (Exit the shells to continue the boot process.)
>
>   BOOT_DEBUG=0
>
>   This is the default.
>
>   BOOT_DEBUG=1
>
>   More verbose than usual.
>
>   BOOT_DEBUG=2
>
>   Lots of debugging information.
>
>   BOOT_DEBUG=3
>
>   Shells are run at various points in the boot process to allow detailed debugging. Exit the shell to continue the boot.

In addition there is section: "[5.4. Troubleshooting the Installation Process - Chapter 5. Booting the Installation System](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s04.en.html)":

> **5.4.4. Common 32-bit PC Installation Problems**
>
> There are some common installation problems that can be solved or avoided by passing certain boot parameters to the installer.
>
> **If your screen begins to show** a weird picture while the kernel boots, eg. pure white, **pure black** or colored pixel garbage, **your system may contain a problematic video card which does not switch to the framebuffer mode properly**. Then you can use the boot parameter **fb=false** to disable the framebuffer console. Only a reduced set of languages will be available during the installation due to limited console features. See Section 5.3, “Boot Parameters” for details.

Also note the section: "5.4.5. Interpreting the Kernel Startup Messages", "5.4.6. Reporting Installation Problems", and "5.4.7. Submitting Installation Reports", If you still have problems, please submit an installation report.

Whether asking for help here or there, there's a minimum amount of information you will need to provide and a list of standard things to try (which is useful to mention before asking for further assistance).

Comment: I have already attempted editing the boot xommand using 'e', as suggested in that post. However, that did not have any effect for me. Neither did the suggestion to turn off framebuffer. In both cases I see no output at all, not even text, so I cant offer any additional information because none is available to me.

Comment: "I see no output at all ..." - If everything is always blank (even when you hit "e") then it is possible to use the "log_host, log_port" to monitor the progress. Alternatively if you can boot a live CD you can mount the drive you used and look in /var/log or if using [systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/) that webpage mentions: "... let it retry for up to 5 minutes before declaring it definitely stuck. There is a chance that a service that has trouble starting will be killed after this timeout and the boot will continue normally. ... you will be in emergency mode."

Answer (score 0):

I have a new ThinkPad P1 and I got the installer working on Live USB after enabling CSM in BIOS. This was mentioned here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899240